# jQuery - call function onmouseout but only if the cursor wasn't moved to a certain area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this link:

```
<a class='itemshow'>Show Details</a>
```

When this link is hovered over, a div opens up below it with some content. That works fine. Now, I need a .mouseout() event which closes the div that was opened (div's id is gen_details) but ONLY if the cursor wasn't moved down to the div itself.

I have written a function which closes the div (see below, slideToggle does it), I just need a modification - a condition that checks whether the cursor is within the div's boundaries, and only executes the code if it's not.

```
    $('a.itemshow').mouseleave(function()
        { 
//if(condition here to check if cursor is out of the div's boundaries){
        if($('#gen_details').hasClass("open")){
            $('#gen_details').slideToggle(300);
            $('#gen_details').removeClass("open");
                return false;
            }
//}
        });
```

Shouldn't be too complex but I can't figure out how to do it without any complicated hacks.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing is usually solved with a small timeout that's cleared if the mouse enters a certain element. Something like:

```
var timer;

$('a.itemshow, #gen_details').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $("#gen_details").slideDown(300);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        timer = setTimeout(hideGen, 200);  
    }
});

function hideGen() {
    $("#gen_details").slideUp(300);
}
```

​[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vuqjy/)

Comment: Works fine on the fiddle, but not on my page. You see, I already have a hover event which opens the div after 2 seconds, positions it properly etc. When I add your mouseleave event to that, it closes the div with the 200ms timeout as soon as I leave the link, regardless of the div. My attempt at a fiddle, which gives an error for some reason I can't figure out: http://jsfiddle.net/5VsMy/

Answer (score 0):

No need for timers or anything like that. You just set the mouseover function to select both the link as well as the div. So if you are hovering over your containing div it does the default action and move away from the div or link then the mouseout handler is called, not sure you get what I mean.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/avukonke/fcSUH/

```
<a href="www.twitter.com" class="tester"><img src="https://blog.twitter.com/sites/all/themes/gazebo/img/twitter-bird-white-on-blue.png" /></a>

<div style="width:200px; height: 100px; background-color:black; clear:none;" class="myblock"></div>
```